How to configure collectd-snmp to only report when things have changed?
I have an SNMP interface TX/RX data source that updates roughly every 10 seconds, and a collectd daemon monitoring it.
With a default Interval of 10s, I noticed that some of my data points, occasionally contain 2 updates (20 seconds worth of data), instead of the expected 10s. Other times it can contain 0 updates (0 seconds worth of data), due to minor races between the SNMP source's 10 second update and collectd 10 second poll time.
Is it possible to configure the collectd snmp plugin to poll more often, perhaps every 2 seconds, with a Scale 5.0, but discard all data points where nothing has changed since the previous polling?
Alternatively, are there any better ways to have collectd snmp wait for the upstream to update before collecting its data point?
